# Android - Creating a new Facebook album creates two albums

Tags: android, facebook

I am using the following code to create a new facebook album.  It works - but it creates the album twice!  It is only called from one place, it is not called from anywhere else.

I am tearing my hair out trying to work out why this is happening.  Could it be something to do with the Session?  The Create New Album code is called on a button click in the OnCreate()

```
 mButtonPost.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            createNewAlbum(Session.getActiveSession(), "new album for photos");
        }

    });
```

This is the code to create the album:

```
public void createNewAlbum(Session session, String albumName) {
if (session.isOpened()) {

    SessionState state = session.getState();
    if (state.isOpened()) { //added this 

    Bundle params = new Bundle();
    params.putString("name", albumName);

    Request.Callback callback = new Request.Callback() {

        @Override
        public void onCompleted(Response response) {

            // use response id to upload photo to that album
            errText.setText("New Album created response: " + response.toString());

            //need to get the newly created album ID.
            try
            {
                JSONObject graphResponse =response.getGraphObject().getInnerJSONObject();

                try
                {
                    albID = graphResponse.getString("id");

                    //UPLOAD photos to that album
                    UploadToAlbum(Session.getActiveSession(), albID);
                }
                catch (JSONException e)
                {
                    Log.d( "JSON error "+ e.getMessage(), albID );
                    albID =null;
                }

            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                albID = null;
            }
        }
    };


    Request request = new Request(session, "me/albums",params, HttpMethod.POST,callback);
    request.executeAsync();

    }//end state session is opened

    }//end session if
}
```

Is there anything obvious here?
When the Activity loads, I call "LogInToFacebook()".
Then the button is clicked and the album is created.
But it is created twice.  Two empty albums are created and both have the SAME ID.  If there is nothing obvious here then I will post my login code too as I really don't understand it.

Comment: Anyone have any ideas why 2 identical albums are being created here?

Comment: I think my issue may be similar to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15295305/facebook-login-callback-fires-multiple-times?rq=1

Comment: Why would the request be executed more than once, is it something to do with callbacks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this is a big in Facebooks GraphAPI -the bug has been assigned to the team to fix, but who knows how long it could be before its fixed!